# How to install Scala plugin manually?

Tags: eclipse, scala

http://www.scala-ide.org/

gives
http://download.scala-ide.org/update-current-35

There are features and plugins directory. Which should I use or both ? Should I just unzip them all in eclipse features and/or plugins directory ?

By the way what diff between features and plugins ?

Comment: I have edited and completed my answer to address the *manual* installation part of the Scala plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should use both: the [update-current-35](http://download.scala-ide.org/update-current-35) is a [p2 site](http://wiki.eclipse.org/P2) you can enter in your "Available Software List" when installing a new software in Eclipse.
Eclipse will detect both features and plugins within that address p2 site, and will install them all.

See this [Scala installation video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtkNg4mK4NY&feature=player_embedded).

The difference between [feature and plugin is explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357234/difference-between-feature-and-plugin-xml/1357327#1357327).

Don't forget to use the right Eclipse version for this installation: [Eclipse Classic 3.5.2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/galileo/sr2).

---

If you need to install it manually, you should copy the full content of the `plugins` and `features` directories from that p2 site in a **[shared dropins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763843/eclipse-plugins-vs-features-vs-dropins/2763891#2763891)** you reference in your eclipse.ini (see this [eclipse.ini for eclipse3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590)).
(you don't need to copy `site.xml`, `contents.jar`, `artifact.jar`)

```
-Dorg.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins.directory=C:/path/to/myPlugins
```

You will create the following tree (similar to another manual installation described in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175248/what-clearcase-plugin-to-use-with-eclipse/1175738#1175738))

```
C:/path/to/myPlugins
  org.scala-ide.1.0.0.201008022319
     eclipse
       features
         ch.epfl.lamp.sdt_2.8.0.scala-ide-upgrade.jar
         org.eclipse.contribution.weaving_1.6.4.scala-ide-upgrade.jar
         org.scala-ide.sdt.feature_1.0.0.201008022319.jar
         org.scala-ide.sdt.weaving.feature_1.0.0.201008022319.jar
       plugins
         org.aspectj.runtime_1.6.9.20100629172100.jar
         org.aspectj.weaver_1.6.9.20100629172100.jar
         org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt_2.1.0.e35x-release-20100630-1500.jar
         org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.aspectj_1.0.0.v20100108.jar
         org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.0.0.v20100108.jar
         org.scala-ide.scala.compiler_2.8.0.jar
         org.scala-ide.scala.library_2.8.0.jar
         org.scala-ide.sdt.aspects_1.0.0.201008022319.jar
         org.scala-ide.sdt.core_1.0.0.201008022319.jar
         org.scala-refactoring.library_0.2.0.201008022305.jar
         scalariform_0.0.5.201007302350.jar
```

Note:

The '`org.scala-ide.1.0.0.201008022319`' folder directly under myPlugins could be any name actually! I just took a name inspired from the features id, to clearly identify the exact Scala plugin you are installing.
If you have several Scala versions in your `myPlugins`, p2 will detect the most recent one automatically, even if you install them in '`a/eclipse/...`', '`b/eclipse/...`', '`c/eclipse/...`'.
I simply find '`org.scala-ide.1.0.0.201008022319`' more precise than '`a`', '`b`' or '`c`', in order to remember what exact plugins I have in my shared dropins.

You need to have the right Eclipse version (classic 3.5.2) in order to be sure to include all the dependencies the Scala plugin might need.

---

Local installation:

You could create the very same tree ('`org.scala-ide.1.0.0.201008022319/eclipse/....`') within the 'dropins' directory within your eclipse.
You won't need to declared a shared dropins directory in your `eclipse.ini`.

I just prefer using a shared dropins because I have many eclipse installations, but if you have the right eclipse, you can make the same tree directly in `</path/to/your/eclipse/dropins>`.

---

Dirty installation:

Finally, you could:

- copy the content of '`http://download.scala-ide.org/update-current-35/plugins/`' in the `plugins` directory of your eclipse.
- copy the content of '`http://download.scala-ide.org/update-current-35/features/`' in the `features` directory of your eclipse.

But I find that not very clean, because it mixes up the native plugins coming with your Eclipse distro and the extra plugins you are adding.

Comment: Hi I know how to install this plugin with the url, my question is about installing it MANUALLY :)

Comment: Could I also use this with Galilleo version ? http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started

Comment: @asksuperu: yes you can, but the "Supported dropins formats" leads to the same tree structure I mention in my answer. And the bundle pooling is a bit more complex than a shared dropins (I mentioned bundle pooling [in this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582391/installing-eclipse-3-4-plugins-in-a-directory-other-than-eclipsehome-plugins/582430#582430)).

Answer (score 6):

Just Drag and Drop Scala IDE your eclipse. You can find the drag drop image file (Install) in below link.

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/scala-ide

http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro?mpc_install=421

Then follow the installation steps.

[image]

Comment: I dropped the Install icon from http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/scala-ide into my IDE, as you suggested, and consequently i can use Eclipse. But now, if i copy my eclipse installation to another machine, when i open the IDE in the other machine, i don't see Scala (e.g. there is no Scala perspective). How come?

Answer (score 6):

For neon version of eclipse, we can add Scala plug-ins by following below steps.

1. Help --> Install New Software
2. Click on Add button next to "Work with" text field.
3. Enter "http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e46/scala211/stable/site" in location and give some name that you can remember.
4. Scala related plug-in tree is listed. Choose the components to add.
5. Click next, next , finish.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old question, and perhaps better handled /answered by various sites, though i just added the following as an update site, and installed relevant pieces !!

http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/lithium/e44/scala211/stable/site

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am using Eclipse IDE and then added Scala plugin follow the below steps simply:

Go to the “Help” option on top of your Eclipse IDE on the dashboard.

http://commandstech.com/how-to-add-scala-plugin-in-sts-eclipse-ide-on-ubuntu/

The above source is worked for me.