# eclipse RCP UI through java code

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Can I implement Eclipse RCP UI using java code only and not `plugin.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it might be possible in theory ([eclipse plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357234/difference-between-feature-and-plugin-xml/1357327#1357327) are [OSGi bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695305/eclipse-rcp-target-platform-eclipse-vs-equinox/3695492#3695492) which are [read by the extension registry](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=37876&S=0fc8beb13ad6fe2e22081452e96fd645#page_top)), I don't think it is practical (unless you re-implement the extension registry lifecycle).

[Eclipse Equinox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695305/eclipse-rcp-target-platform-eclipse-vs-equinox/3695492#3695492) precisely extends the concept of bundles with the concept of [extension points](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html), hence the mandatory presence of `plugin.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically add and remove extensions. See following example methods (adapt on demand):

```java
public void addExtension() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String pluginXmlAsString = "<a string with the content of plugin.xml";
    InputStream pluginXmlIs = new ByteArrayInputStream(pluginXmlAsString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name()));

    IExtensionRegistry extensionRegistry = Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
    Object token = ((ExtensionRegistry) extensionRegistry).getTemporaryUserToken();
    IContributor contributor = ContributorFactoryOSGi.createContributor(Platform.getBundle("org.acme.mybundle"));

    extensionRegistry.addContribution(pluginXmlIs, contributor, false, null, null, token);
}

public static void removeExtensionsContributedByMe() {
    String extensionPointId = "<ID of the extension point for remove an extension of";
    String extensionContributor = "org.acme.mybundle";

    ExtensionRegistry extensionRegistry = (ExtensionRegistry) Platform.getExtensionRegistry();
    IExtensionPoint extensionPoint = extensionRegistry.getExtensionPoint(extensionPointId);
    IExtension[] extensions = extensionPoint.getExtensions();
    Object token = extensionRegistry.getTemporaryUserToken();

    for (IExtension extension : extensions) {
        if (extensionContributor.equals(extension.getContributor().getName())) {
            extensionRegistry.removeExtension(extension, token);
        }
    }
}
```

We use this for unit tests which add extensions as preparation and remove extension to clean up. This way the tests do not influence each other (which would be the case if the extensions are "hard coded" in plugin.xml or fragment.xml).